# Remove oem.inf files corresponding to hardware id

Tags: c, windows, winapi, driver, device-driver

I'm installing my driver using dpinst.exe. But before installing my driver I wish to delete all the oem files from inf directory corresponding to my hardware ID.

I want to do this programatically. Please suggest me a way to do this.

```
**Update :**
```

I want to do this without device connected as I may pre-install the driver before connecting the device. My device is PNP device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use [SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551010%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551967%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to match your hardware ID
2. Use [SetupDiOpenDevRegKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552079%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [RegQueryValueEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724911%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to read the corresponding `InfPath`
3. Call [SetupUninstallOEMInf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa377446%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: This method works for me when the device is not connected, so maybe you are using different parameters. Can you post some code?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply PhilMy. my device is a Plug and play device which comes under ports class. Once I unplug my device the entry from device manager will be removed as its a PNP. And SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo enumerate only the devices available in device manager if am not wrong? Please correct me if am wrong. Sorry I didnt start my coding part as am still analysing it..

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clear answer. I finally finished my coding part and please refer this link http://pastebin.com/uHihC4gV. I face few problems in it 1) my RegQueryValueEx fails with error (6) and 2) SetupUninstallOEMInf deletes only the non readonly files. Can you please check my code for som corrections atleast to get rid of regqueryvalueEx error.

Comment: Check whether `hDeviceKey` is being set to `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` and if so call `GetLastError()` for more information. There's a comment on the [SetupUninstallOEMInf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa377446%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) page that suggests you can manually [clear the read-only attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365522(v=vs.85).aspx) in advance.

Comment: yes you are right I get 'INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE' by checking 'hDeviceKey' but only once. I commented the SetupUninstallOEMInf and tried printing only the path of the inf file and here is the link of the output for your reference http://pastebin.com/2WPf1HsM. Any tips to solve this if possible..

Comment: I am able to retreive around 5 INF paths matched with my h/w id following your step 1 & 2.One INF contains driver for other device. However the registry maps with H/W id. Does windows reallocate the OEM.inf to other device?Previously,I used to remove the OEM INF/PNF files, without deleting registry entry. Am I doing anything wrong?Please advice..

Answer (score 0):

PhilMY has already posted an excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11470652/2136186), which is still relevant. However, it is more than ten years old now, so I wanted to update it with more recent/recommended APIs:

1. Use [`SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupdienumdeviceinfo) and [`SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupdigetdeviceregistrypropertyw) to match your hardware ID
2. To get the OEM INF path, [`SetupDiGetDriverInfoDetail()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupdigetdriverinfodetailw) can be used instead of reading the registry directly
3. Call [`DiUninstallDriver()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/newdev/nf-newdev-diuninstalldriverw) on the resulting INF path (Microsoft recommends using it instead of `SetupUninstallOEMInf()`. In addition, it returns the `needReboot` flag, which may be useful in some scenarios.)

#2 is a little tricky as it requires `SP_DRVINFO_DATA` on input. To acquire it, one typically needs to call [`SetupDiBuildDriverInfoList()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupdibuilddriverinfolist) and [`SetupDiEnumDriverInfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupdienumdriverinfow) to iterate through all installed drivers for a particular device (use `SPDIT_COMPATDRIVER` flag to enumerate 3rd-party drivers).

It has a significant advantage in scenarios when multiple drivers are suitable for the given device, and this approach allows one to choose exactly which driver to uninstall.